# How to install mono 3.2 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I really need to know how to install mono 3.2 or higher in ubuntu 13.04. This is because for my computer science class, we will be coding in VB.net. Please note, I DO NOT WANT TO INSTALL ANY KIND OF VIRTUAL MACHINE OR GAMBAS. Also, is there an opposite of sudo apt-get dist-upgrade to undo what you have installed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry everyone. I've solved my own problem:

http://forums.osgrid.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=4625